# Parallelizing modifications to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing

I have a dictionary `my_dict` containing lists, and an iterable `keys` with a lot of keys which I would like to run a function on:

```
for key in keys:
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key].append(my_fun(key, params))
    else:
        my_dict[key] = [my_fun(key, params)]
```

`my_fun` is slow. How do I parallellize this loop?

---

Is it just:

```
import multiprocessing

def _process_key(key): 
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key].append(my_fun(key, params))
    else:
        my_dict[key] = [my_fun(key, params)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(_process_key, keys)
```

Comment: No, the dict needs to be updated in the parent.

Comment: I am a bit confused... you call `my_fun` multiple times with the same key... I assume that's intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dict` is in the parent memory space so you need to update it there. `pool.map` iterates through whatever is returned by the worker function, so just have it return it in a useful form. `collections.defaultdict` is a helper that creates items for you, so you can

```
import multiprocessing
import collections

def _process_key(key): 
    return key, my_fun(key, params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for key, val in p.map(_process_key, keys):
            my_dict[key].append(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is not good at *CPU-bound* multithreadng, because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). If you want to speed up a CPU-bound computation, use `multiprocessing`.

I would split the keys of your dictionary into as many lists as you have cores available. Then I would pass these lists to subprocesses, along with the original dictionary, or a relevant part of it (if values are large object graphs).

The subprocesses would return partial results, that the main process would merge into a single result.

For *I/O-bound* computations, the same approach would work using `threading`, which could be faster because the data would be directly shared between threads.

The above is pretty generic. I don't know how to best partition your key space for even load and maximum speedup; you have to experiment.